# What happens to a return value if it's not "captured"?

Tags: .net-3.5, filestream

A project I'm working on has the following line of code:

```
 File.Create(path);
```

This method returns a `FileStream` object. If this doesn't get closed, I can't write to the file that was created.

So, to solve that, I could do something like this:

```
var fs = File.Create(path);
fs.Close();
```

or simply...

```
File.Create(path).Close();
```

Those two snippets make sense to me, because I'm calling a method on my file stream object.  But in my first block of code, I don't understand where the filestream goes / what happens to it. Why is it retained in memory if I'm not keeping it in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It's in a buffer in memory until you either .flush() the stream or .close() the stream telling it to write to the disk. If you don't do either of those when **writing** to a stream it never leaves the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

FileStream inherits from Stream, which implements the IDisposable interface. You should always dispose it, because it will use resources not directly under the runtime's control.

What happens if you don't dispose of it yourself is that the Garbage Collector will eventually destroy the instance of a FileStream you have there - but the underlying system resources related to the file might not be recovered by the system. That is, you'll have a the stream there but it will be inacessible. It will just be occupying space in memory. You probably won't be able to edit or delete that file in other programs (even other instances of your application) until the OS itself forces the release of the resources you've locked.